# Place DLLs in other dir

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I want to place DLLs of my game to another folder then exe file because it is a huge mess. (I use SDL2 but it is not relevant for this I guess)

Edit: How can I import DLL from another direktory ? (I import them just trought headers)

Comment: I fail to see the question here.

Comment: Please ask a question.

Comment: Best plan is to put the DLLs in the same directory as the exe.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan As a general rule of thumb. But for complex solutions I'd wager organization could be nice. I don't know why this question got downvoted actually, and I ask from the downvoter (whoever) to please explain.

Comment: @Ken Whilst it might be nice, the loader really prefers dlls in same dir as exe

Comment: The loader has no preferences. It simply does what it is told to do.

Comment: You can do it with a manifest that contains the `<dependentAssembly>` element to declare a private dependency.  This is so poorly documented that it isn't worth the hassle.

Comment: @IInspectable if you want load time linking, then you cannot tell it what to do

Comment: @Hans That's interesting, and you are right about it being poorly documented. I couldn't find anything that allows specifying a search path. Are you implying that the `<assemblyIdentity>`s `name` attribute can contain a relative path? Or am I just misinterpreting you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this to work you need to specify your libraries as [`/DELAYLOAD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9zd12s.aspx) and set the appropriate DLL directories during application startup calling [`AddDllDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310513.aspx) (Windows 8 and above) or [`SetDllDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203.aspx) (Windows XP SP1 and above).

Delay loading of DLLs is required in this scenario. Otherwise the loader will try to resolve the import tables before your application gets a chance to set the appropriate directories to search for.

Comment: Are there any cons for delay loading?

Comment: @Ken Errors about postponed import resolution come in later (the first time you attempt to use an unsatisfied import). For a robust solution you are required to implement appropriate [Error Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3aeywt27.aspx). There are also some [Constraints of Delay Loading DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx1x886y.aspx).

Comment: @Ken I have no experience with `/DELAYLOAD` but I can think of two minor problems: 1) easier to accidentally forget to distribute a DLL that is rarely used (because program will only attempt to load it, and thus display error, after first call to a function in that DLL) 2) you are also potentially trading longer start up time for a shorter one but with a possibility of a (probably quite minor) spike each time new DLL is loaded.

Comment: @user2802841 Your first point is usually not a problem. Even if you get hit by it once, you will then include a test for this into your QA testing. The second point reads more like a pro than a con.

Comment: @IInspectable I agree they are both very minor and it's probably too much to call them problems :)

Answer (score -1):

The `PATH` environment variable should do the trick

Comment: That's a global solution to a local problem

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Make it local - have a batch file?!

Comment: It is still global. It doesn't only affect calls to `LoadLibrary`.